# Some people can't download a public object in S3 via direct s3 link that is emailed to them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So there's a public file https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/attachment/folder/file.csv that can be downloaded by almost all people who receive this link via email.

Nevertheless, there are some people that hit this link and receive the following message from S3:
[image]

I've checked permissions for the object. They look fine afaik.
[image: an object's permissions in s3]

If "Object ACL" needs to be checked as well and it's the only thing that needs to be done, could you please point me to the place in AWS docs where this field is described, because I haven't found it.

If sharing a direct public link to s3 object simply doesn't work, could you share your reasons apart from the bucket's security point of view?

Pointing out any other problem will also be appreciated

Comment: That is strange. You confirm that the final link they visit on browser URL is correct already? Sometimes the mail client may mess up special characters. Otherwise, I suggest opening a support ticket for AWS

Comment: What about timeout? How long is your presigned URL valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the email clients our clients used. Thanks to everyone who contributed and didn't, but put some mental effort into trying to come up with a suggestion that would help us. Shout out to @qkhanpro for a close-to-true suggestion. I'm now closing this question.